# Identification of unknowns with varying solubilities and states of matter

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, identification

> White solid **A** water insoluble cleaved hot to solid gas **B** and **C**. **B** is insoluble in water and in $\ce{HCl}$ but soluble to $\ce{HNO3}$ the react gives solution **D** and **E** colorless gas which becomes red on contact with air. The solution **D** gave white precipitate **F** with $\ce{HCl}$. The gas **C** is reacted by heating with magnesium **G** yielding a white solid which reacts with water yielding a white solid and the gas **J** characteristic suffocating odor. **J** is a basic , **H** is soluble in dilute $\ce{H2SO4}$. The gas **J** oxidized to **C** while the gas under specific conditions ($\ce{Pt}$ catalyst and $800^\circ\mathrm{C}$) is oxidized to the gas **E**.

My attempt:
**C**: $\ce{N2}$,
**G**: $\ce{Mg3N2}$,
**H**: $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$,
**J**: $\ce{NH3}$,
**E**: $\ce{NO}$
\begin{aligned}\ce{ 
N2 + 3Mg &-> Mg3N2\\
 Mg3N2 + 6H2O &-> 3Mg(OH)2 + 2NH3\\
 Mg(OH)2 + H2SO4 &<=> 2 H2O + MgSO4\\
 4 NH3 + 5 O2 &->[\ce{Pt~$800^\circ\mathrm{C}$}] 6 H2O + 4 NO\\
 4 NH3 + 3 O2 &-> 6 H2O + 2 N2\\
}\end{aligned}

I cannot really find anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions which you have already found look good so far. For solid **A**, we need to find a compound which thermally decomposes into $\ce{N2}$ and an element which is only soluble in oxidizing acids like $\ce{HNO3}$, and whose chloride is insoluble in water or acids. [Silver azide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_azide) could possibly be a good fit, as it can be cleaved into $\ce{Ag}$ and $\ce{N2}$ by heating, and [silver chloride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_chloride) has a very low solubility in water. Care would have to be taken with the temperature when actually performing the decomposition of $\ce{AgN3}$, as it is explosive.

$$\ce{2AgN3 -> 3N2\uparrow + 2Ag}$$

Dissolving silver (solid **B**) in nitric acid gives a [silver nitrate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_nitrate) solution **D** and $\ce{NO}$ as colorless gas **E**.

$$\ce{3Ag + 4HNO3 -> 3AgNO3 + 2H2O + NO\uparrow}$$

$\ce{NO}$ turns red on contact with air when it is oxidized to [nitrogen dioxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_dioxide) by atmospheric oxygen.

$$\ce{2NO + O2 <=> 2NO2}$$

From solution **D**, insoluble $\ce{AgCl}$ (**F**) precipitates when $\ce{HCl}$ is added.

$$\ce{Ag+ + Cl- -> AgCl\downarrow}$$